# Need to choose between Azure App Insights and Google Analytics

Tags: azure, google-analytics

I Need to choose between Azure App Insights and Google Analytics which should i choose give the detailed explanation why and how

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is that you are actually wanting to do with  them ? Is it Simple info like page view statistics or application detailed information ?

Comment: I want to check my application performance and track of visitors viewing the pages for that i can use Google Analytics or Azure App Insights.